# How do i prove $(1-\frac{t}{n})^n < e^{-t}$ when $0<t<n$?

Tags: real-analysis

How do i prove : $(1-\frac{t}{n})^n < e^{-t}$ when $0<t<n$?

It seems obvious but i am absurdly struggling this for an hour.. Please help!

It's trivial that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1-\frac{t}{x})^x = e^{-t}$. So it could be proven if it is monotonically increasing. But even the derivative is hard one know its positivity and negativity..

Comment: @abiessu yes it's written in a text. Frank Jones - Lebesgue integration

Comment: My bad, I mixed up my multiplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a $\ln$ from both sides. Then consider the function $f(x) = x+\ln(1-x)$ in the interval $[0,1)$. It is decreasing.

Comment: Outstanding..! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Extending and detailing kmitov's answer:

Getting $\ln$ from both sides gives:
$$n\ln(1-\frac tn)<-t$$
Dividing by $n$ and putting $x=\frac t n$ gives:
$$\ln(1-x)<-x,\space 0<x<1$$
Or $f(x)=\ln(1-x)+x<0$.

The derivative of $f(x)$ is $1-\frac{1}{1-x}$ which is negative for $0<x<1$, so the function is decreasing. $f(0)=\ln(1)+0=0$. So $f(x)$ is negative for $0<x<1$ and the inequality holds as needed.